# Nhibernate - Database side queries

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, filter, expression

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41810306/appointment-scheduling....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code.

The first is how you are declaring your method:

```
Func<T, bool> ComposeFilter
```

When you do that, you are returning a compiled delegate, and the `Where` extension method overload that gets chosen is from `Enumerable` instead of `Queryable`.

You have to declare it as:

```
Expression<Func<T, bool>> ComposeFilter
```

The second problem is that the code you wrote cannot be converted to an expression tree. Since you are not using primitives but constructing the expression dynamically, you need to learn about the stuff in `System.Linq.Expressions`.

Comment: ok that's was what i expected, i need to build an expression rather than a function. I wonder why i didn't get a "Not supported exception". Does NHibernate reconize string.Contains function ?

Comment: NHibernate was never seeing your code. As soon as `Enumerable` takes over, the unfiltered query is executed, and then the results are filtered by Linq-to-objects.